# Unit Test for classes that extend SysOperationServiceBase

Tags: unit-testing, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

My question is simple for someone who has a good experience in developing for AX.

Do we write Unit tests for classes that extends `SysOperationServiceBase`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should write unit tests for classes that extend the SysOperationServiceBase, because they contain business logic.
Perhaps you could provide more details on why you wouldn't write unit tests for that particular set of classes?